# Selecting a relational database

Tags: mysql

I tried selecting a relational database with this code:

```
$page_set=mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM pages WHERE  subject_id = 
{$subject["id"]}", $connection) ;
```

database query failed:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

My mysql sever version is 5.1.62

Comment: Now would be a really good time to abandon this deprecated API.

Comment: You are inside double quotes already, switch your array stuff to: `{$subject['id']}`

Comment: [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)? -- function not found. If you are reading a tutorial and it teaches you how to use `mysql_query()` then it is a bad tutorial. Find a better one.

Comment: It returned thesame error@JNevill

Comment: Perhaps build that sql string into a seperate variable and output the results then. Something is going wrong with your variable and that will quickly tell you what it is.

Comment: Pls can you show me how?@JNevill

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$page_set=mysql_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE  subject_id =". $subject["id"]) ;
```

Comment: @chubi what was the error could you please specify.